# Error in audio recording WAV

Tags: wav, audio-recording, naudio

I have two methods that record audio every 10 minutes, alternating each method, properly recorded during the first 6 or 7 hours, but then I generates large files to twice normal to hear hear bad but only happens with a method other Normal still recording. I use to record WaveInEnvent since the method is inside a thread, I think problem is in OnDataAvailable.

Here the code used:

```
       wavein = new WaveInEvent();
       wavein.Dispose();
       wavein.DeviceNumber = 0;
       wavein.NumberOfBuffers = 11;
       wavein.BufferMilliseconds = 1000;
       wavein.WaveFormat = new WaveFormat(8000, 16, 2);
       wavein.DataAvailable += OnDataAvailable;
       wavein.RecordingStopped += OnRecordingStopped;
       writer = new WaveFileWriter(outfilename, wavein.WaveFormat);
       bufferedWaveProvider = new BufferedWaveProvider(wavein.WaveFormat);
       bufferedWaveProvider.DiscardOnBufferOverflow = true;
       wavein.StartRecording();

private void OnDataAvailable(object sender, WaveInEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.InvokeRequired)
        {
            //Debug.WriteLine("Data Available");
            this.BeginInvoke(new EventHandler<WaveInEventArgs>(OnDataAvailable), sender, e);
        }
        else
        {
            if (writer != null)
                {
                 try
                    {

                        for (int i = 0; i < e.BytesRecorded; i += 2)
                        {
                            short sample = (short)((e.Buffer[i + 1] << 8) | e.Buffer[i + 0]);
                            float sample32 = sample / 32768f;

                            writer.WriteByte(e.Buffer[i + 0]);
                            writer.WriteByte(e.Buffer[i + 1]);

                        }

                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                     {
                    // Log error
                     }
                    }

                }
       }
```